# ActionBar logo scaled down behavior

Tags: android

I see that depending on how an image is set as the logo for ActionBar's home button, the image appears scaled down.

**Image is scaled when using one of the following:**

1. `Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.logo);
    actionBar.setLogo(new BitmapDrawable(bmp));`
2. `Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
    actionBar.setLogo(new BitmapDrawable(bmp));`

   **Image is NOT scaled, it looks OK when using one of the following:**
3. `Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.logo);
    actionBar.setLogo(getResources(), new BitmapDrawable(bmp));`
4. `Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
    actionBar.setLogo(getResources(), new BitmapDrawable(bmp));`
5. `actionBar.setLogo(R.drawable.logo)`

For all cases, I call `actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true)`.

Compared to 1 and 2, 3 and 4 respectively pass Resources parameter to setLogo.

I would like to understand why passing Resources influence the logo size.